# Lost updates in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, updates, datastax, consistency

I am facing problems of lost writes while updating a row in Cassandra. Here's my schema:

```
create table balances(
id bigint,
balance decimal,
last_transaction_id bigint,
update_timestamp timestamp,
type varchar,
is_balance_valid boolean, 
primary key (wallet_id)
)
```

Total nodes in cluster: 3 in Local DC
Replication factor: 2
Cassandra Version: 2.1.8

I update the value of column "**balance**" every time user does a transaction by reading the previously set value, adding the transaction amount and issuing the update. I am using Java, Datastax driver (2.1.5).

Once out of about half a million transactions, one particular update would fail. This happens usually when the user has done two transactions in quick succession, down to few milliseconds. Here are logs:

> Transaction #1
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:15:16,984 -[pool-11-thread-1]-  INFO -
>   ScratchpadMasterStreamProcessor.processMessage(62) - Printing str id:
>   1466140282Scratchpad id: 9127013322
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:15:16,986 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(43) - **Current balance: 0.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:15:16,986 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(44) - **Deviation : 200.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:15:16,986 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   UserBalanceManager.updateWalletBalance(70) - Updating user..510978682
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:15:16,987 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(51) - **Final Balance: 200.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:15:16,987 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   ScratchpadMasterStreamProcessor.processMessage(79) - Balance Update
>   was successful for wallet 510978682
>
> Transaction #2
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,157 -[pool-11-thread-1]-  INFO -
>   ConsumerThread.run(82) - Event Recieved
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,159 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(43) - **Current balance: 200.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,159 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(44) - **Deviation : 50.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,159 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   UserBalanceManager.updateWalletBalance(70) - Updating user..510978682
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,160 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(51) - **Final Balance: 250.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,160 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   ScratchpadMasterStreamProcessor.processMessage(79) - Balance Update
>   was successful for wallet 510978682
>
> Transaction #3 (This is lost)
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,160 -[pool-11-thread-1]-  INFO -
>   ScratchpadMasterStreamProcessor.processMessage(62) - Printing str id:
>   1466162182Scratchpad id: 9127117934
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,161 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(43) - **Current balance: 250.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,161 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(44) - **Deviation : -250.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,161 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   UserBalanceManager.updateWalletBalance(70) - Updating user..510978682
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,162 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(51) - **Final Balance: 0.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:19,162 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   ScratchpadMasterStreamProcessor.processMessage(79) - Balance Update
>   was successful for wallet 510978682
>
> Transaction #4 Read stale balance, oops
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:23,140 -[pool-11-thread-1]-  INFO -
>   ConsumerThread.run(82) - Event Recieved
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:23,140 -[pool-11-thread-1]-  INFO -
>   ScratchpadMasterStreamProcessor.processMessage(62) - Printing str id:
>   1466162730Scratchpad id: 9127120830
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:23,141 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(43) - **Current balance: 250.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:23,141 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(44) - **Deviation : 200.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:23,141 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   UserBalanceManager.updateWalletBalance(70) - Updating user..510978682
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:23,142 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   SclwBalanceUpdater.updateBalance(51) - **Final Balance: 450.0**
>
> 10 Feb 2016 18:18:23,142 -[pool-11-thread-1]- DEBUG -
>   ScratchpadMasterStreamProcessor.processMessage(79) - Balance Update
>   was successful for wallet 510978682

I have set consistency level to LOCAL_QUORUM for both reads and writes, and the three cassandra node servers have same time (using NTP). What could be the problem?

Comment: Database like Cassandra have significant advantages when it comes to scaling up, distribution to several data centers and availability. But it comes at the price of reduced consistency guarantees. And that's most likely what you're experiencing. I'm not sure Cassandra is the right choice if the balance needs to be exact under all circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please take a look on Codo's comment that describes very well *why* do you have a problem.

However I'd like to suggest a solution without moving to other DB. 
You can use counter type for your `balance` field. The update statement of counter works differently. It sends to cassandra command to increase/decrease the field by cirtain value, so you will not have a problem of inconsistency.

The counter based solution however is not good for all applications. For example it is limited to integer type. Probably more common solution is to create a kind of transaction programmatically: save update requests in separate table and create asynchronous procedure that aggregates all update requests done during certain period of time and applies them to the `balance` value.

Comment: Actually, balance is floating point, so using counters will not work. For the second point, this would mean that when reading, I'll have to do lookups in two tables, and keep a marker to keep track of transaction which have not been aggregated. Either I delete a lot of rows or my second table becomes huge, both I think will not be useful as reads would slow down.

Comment: Just multiply it by 100 and store it as int (for example in cents instead of dollars). If this does not match your requirements, read the second part of my suggestion.

Comment: Well, I do require the value of balance to be correct all the time. Secondly, using a counter is also no guarantee that stale reads will be prevented [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953821/how-to-rapidly-increment-counters-in-cassandra-w-o-staleness)

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is very good with immutable data and idempotent operations. Not so much with transactions or frequent updates/deletes.

One quick check is if you are using **light weight transactions**. They come at a performance cost but maybe necessary in important data. For example,

```
UPDATE balances
SET balance = <new_balance>
WHERE id = <wallet_id>
IF balance = <old_balance>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a race condition for update operations. Cassandra does not update data, but inserts a new one with another timestamp. Data with the last timestamp is the actual version of the data.

Do you specify timestamps for update queries?

Timestamps allow you to provide the correct sequence for a mutation operation.
If you don't specify the timestamp result of Transaction#3, it can be overwritten by Transaction#2 because they are done in quick succession.