# Increment and get value of counter

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

Is there a way to increment a counter and then get the value back in a single call?

Or is the only way to make 2 calls?

Comment: Do you want the value before the increment, after the increment, or both before and after?

Comment: @EliSadoff I want the value after the increment.

Comment: As scala doesn't have a `++` operator, you must increment the counter then return the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a phantom limitation but a Cassandra API one, there is nothing in CQL that allows you to retrieve and update the value in the same API call, and there's a very very good reason for that.

When you update the value of a counter the CQL looks like this:

```
UPDATE keyspace.table SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE a = b;
```

However, this masks away the true distributed locking complexity Cassandra must undergo to perform a seemingly simple increment. This is because it's really hard to make sure that every count is updating the `latest` value and that multiple increments of the same counter will wind up with the same value.

So you need a guarantee of the write being acknowledged by enough replicas after which you can perform a safe read, and this is making it sound really easy. In reality there's an incremental merge/compare-and-set process that goes on in a single counter increment, better detailed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953821/how-to-rapidly-increment-counters-in-cassandra-w-o-staleness).

The read operation is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace.table WHERE a = b;
```

If you think you are saving much network wise or complexity wise by doing this, you probably aren't unless the volume of read/writes is immense. In short, it's a happy thought but I wouldn't bother.

```
for {
  inc <- database.table.update.where(_.a = b).modify(_.counter increment 1).future()
  value <- database.table.select(_.counter).where(_.a = b).one()
} yield value
```